# Bound on the number of solutions of a polynomial system

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let us consider a set $\mathcal{P}=\left\{  p_{1},p_{2},p_{3},p_{4}\right\}  $
of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}\left[  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}\right]  $:

$p_{1}\left(  x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}\right)  =\left(  x_{1}\left(
x_{1}-1\right)  \right)  ^{2}+\left(  \left(  x_{1}-1\right)  \left(
x_{2}-1\right)  \right)  ^{2}+\left(  \left(  x_{3}-1\right)  \left(
x_{4}-1\right)  \right)  ^{2}$

$p_{2}\left(  x_{2}\right)  =x_{2}^{2}-x_{2}$

$p_{3}\left(  x_{3}\right)  =x_{3}^{2}-x_{3}$

$p_{4}\left(  x_{4}\right)  =x_{4}^{2}-x_{4}$

I have read in the book "Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry" written by
Basu et al., Corollary 12.8, p. 451 that $\#Zer\left(  \mathcal{P}%
,\mathbb{C}^{4}\right)  \leq\#Mon\left(  \mathcal{G}\right)  $ where
$\mathcal{G}$ is a Groebner basis for the ideal generated by $\mathcal{P}$.
The system above is zero-dimensional because $\mathcal{P}$ is actually a
Groebner basis. However $Mon\left(  \mathcal{G}\right)  =\left\{
1,x_{1},x_{1}^{2},x_{1}^{3},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}\right\}  $, i.e. $\#Mon\left(
\mathcal{G}\right)  =7$, and it can be proved that $\left(  x_{1},x_{2}%
,x_{3},x_{4}\right)  \in\left\{  \left(  1,0\right)  ,\left(  0,1\right)
,\left(  1,1\right)  \right\}  \times\left\{  \left(  1,0\right)  ,\left(
0,1\right)  ,\left(  1,1\right)  \right\}  $ are solutions of the polynomial
system $p_{k}=0$. There is something that I do not understand.